# .htaccess RewriteRule to mask url to file

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use the .htaccess to mask an url to a pdf file. Chrome and Edge always open the file and display the url. I used a 301 redirect, to create an alias url wich links to the file, but that seems not to be the right way.

Now I am trying to do this the following way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteRule ^agb?$ wp-content/uploads/2016/07/AGB.pdf$ [L]
```

I am testing this via: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

I would like the url of the pdf file to be masked with "agb" instead of the whole wordpress part.

Seems the first rewrite rule messes up my plan, but at the moment I am totally guessing.

Thanks in advance.

*edit:

I managed to change the .htaccess so it now redirects:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^agb$ wp-content/uploads/2016/07/AGB.pdf$ [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

But what I don't understand is, that the URL in my browser changes. I thought RewriteRules are used to mask the URL, so the user doesn't see the changes happening to the URL, after it has changed.

In my case the user should only see /agb - but instead the whole URL of the file is displayed.

Comment: At least the tester does say, that the rule is not met, when I enter the url to the pdf for it to test.

Comment: https://[site addrress]/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/AGB.pdf

Can't post the address here public yet, as the site is not live yet - sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Your rewrite rule expects URL to be: `https://[site addrress]/agb`

Comment: I thought the RewriteRule works like this:

RewriteRule newUrl oldUrl [flags]

Comment: 1st parameter of `RewriteRule` is a regex pattern and that is `^agb?$`

Comment: Oh - okay. So it would have to be:

RewriteRule ^https://[site address]/agb$ ^[complete url to pdf]$ [L]

?